# Refused to execute script from '{DomainURL}' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

This error show when VF page loading in Production. But it's not showing in Sandboxes.I checked that Content Sniffing protection is enabled in Prod.But i tried to recreate the issue in sandbox by enabling Content Sniffing protection.But it did not work.Do you have any Idea?

Comment: where is that JS sitting. In static resource? Injected from 3rd party server in your VF? In your community's "head" tag?

Comment: Thank you. Solved using article https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000et4XQAQ